# How I can remove only the final numbers in the text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this problem. I want to remove only the final numbers in the String like this "tai-xe-lai-xe-bang-b2kh9088" -> "tai-xe-lai-xe-bang-b2kh". I try to using regex but the result is "tai-xe-lai-xe-bang-bkh" Here is my code

```
const validateSlug= text => {
    const containsNumber =/\d+/
    const textArraySplited = text.split('-')
    // get final text of array splited
    const textSplitedFinal = textArraySplited[textArraySplited.length - 1]

    if (containsNumber.test(textSplitedFinal)) {
      return text.replace(/\d/g, '')
    }
    return text
  }

const a='tai-xe-bang-bk2k8398'
console.log(validateSlug(a)) //the result is tai-xe-bang-bkk but I want the result is tai-xe-bang-bk2k
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try it `/\d+$/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to only remove the numbers that occurred at the end, you could use the end of expression anchor character `$` after your existing expression:

```
 // This will only remove consecutive digits that occur at the end
return text.replace(/\d+$/g, '');
```

### Example

```js
const original = 'tai-xe-lai-xe-bang-b2kh9088';
console.log('Original: ' + original);
console.log('Replaced: ' + original.replace(/\d+$/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var aa = /\d+$/
var s = "tai-xe-bang-bk2k8398"
s.replace(aa,"")
```